# getting multiple values while separating positive and negative values

Tags: sql, oracle

```
create table s4(val number);
INSERT ALL  
  INTO s4 (val) VALUES (1) 
  INTO s4 (val) VALUES (2)  
  INTO s4 (val) VALUES (-1) 
  INTO s4 (val) VALUES (-2)
  select * from dual;


WITH p AS(SELECT val AS Pos FROM s4 WHERE val > 0),
 n  AS (SELECT val AS Neg FROM s4 WHERE val < 0)
 SELECT Pos,Neg FROM p,n
```

Comment: Do you have a question about this? I don't see it.

Comment: how to have single values in result

Comment: What result did you want to get? What should the result be when you add a 3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you might be looking for something like this:

```
SQL> with
  2  p as
  3    (select val as pos,
  4            rownum rn
  5     from s4
  6     where val > 0
  7    ),
  8  n as
  9    (select val as neg,
 10            rownum rn
 11     from s4
 12     where val < 0
 13    )
 14  --
 15  select p.pos, n.neg
 16  from p left join n on n.rn = p.rn     -- more positive values
 17  union
 18  select p.pos, n.neg
 19  from p right join n on n.rn = p.rn;   -- more negative values

       POS        NEG
---------- ----------
         1         -1
         2         -2

SQL>
```

What does it do?

- `rownum` is here so that you could join rows by *something*
- outer joins are used in order to return rows if number of positive values isn't equal to number of negative values (e.g. if you inserted a row whose value is `3`, inner join wouldn't return it)

  - that's what `union` is here, because there might be more negative or more positive values; can't tell which situation will happen